# Ractive recursion with partial - results in Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion, partials, ractivejs

I am new to Ractivejs and I am trying to implement simple partial recursion...

My template is

```
List:<br>
    <ul> 
        {{#list}}
        {{>lipart}}
        {{/list}}
    </ul>

<!-- {{>lipart}} -->
    <li>{{text}} {{#children}} <ul> {{>lipart}} </ul> {{/children}}
<!-- {{/lipart}} -->
```

and my data:

```
list: [
        {text:'item1'}, 
        {text:'item2', children : [{text:'item2a'},{text:'item2b'}] },
        {text:'item3'}
    ]
```

This results in "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please place your answer *as an answer*.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer to my own question. The issue here is described in http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#restricted-references

To resolve the above infinite loop I had to change

```
 {{#children}} ... {{/children}}
```

to

```
 {{#.children}} ... {{/.children}}
```